# C# Windows Forms detect BackColourChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

So I have a windows forms program I am trying to design and I want the draw panel to be able to change colour based on a colour selected from the built in ColorDialog.

I need to detect the firing of the draw panels BackColorChanged event and then have other code happen then. Can anyone tell me how to create a handler for this, feel I may be missing something simple but cant quite figure it out.

Comment: Are you asking how to subscribe to the `BackColorChanged` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be notified when the `BackColorChanged` event is fired, you can subscribe to the `BackColorChanged` event when initializing the form:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        somePanel.BackColorChanged += SomePanel_OnBackColorChanged;
    }

    public void SomePanel_OnBackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Back color has changed, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This works thank you, was blanking on how to subscribe to the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the backcolor of a Panel by choosing a color from a ColorDialog, you don't need no events from that panel.

Open the ColorDialog, wait for it to be closed with "OK" and set the color accordingly:

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
{  
    panel.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;  
}
```

That's what I understood. If you really need to use an event from the Panel, why don't you just use the event every WinForms Control offers: `BackColorChanged`. See Isma's answer for that.

Comment: Sorry should of been clearer I have the colour changed pretty much exactly as you have in your code snippet what I need then is to do more code after that has been changed.

What I am finding is that by using that when debugging if I add other code to the end of that if statement the colour only changes at the end of the if statement so I need to detect if the colour is changed then do the other code.

Comment: Yeah, that's because that code runs synchronously. While the backcolor is set, Windows won't repaint your Panel as long as your method is still running. I would recommend another approach: Don't make parts of your application dependent of an UI event like this. Try to make your method asynchronously (plenty of ways to to that) or - easier but not as good - call `Application.DoEvents()` after setting the color so Windows can do its drawing.